# Xamarin deploy failed

Tags: android, xamarin

I've installed vs2015 community + Xamar to two different platforms - Windows 10 Home and Windows 7.
When I create a simply android app and try to start Android_accelerated_x86 virtual device get I following error  -->

emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: VT feature disabled in BIOS/U.

I've install/uninstall/reinstall visual studio 2015 community several times but end result is same every time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in launching AVD with AMD processor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd-with-amd-processor)

Comment: Inter x86 Emulator Accelator (HAXM installer) is installed but still I get error "Please ensure intel HAXM is properly installed and usable" .

Comment: **"VT feature disabled in BIOS"** https://www.bing.com/search?q=VT+feature+disabled+in+BIOS&form=APMCS1&PC=APMC