# My AVD not working for some reason

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to start the emulator in Android Studio, but for some reason it won't turn on. I've installed HAXM and invalidated caches and restarted AS but it still won't work. It is stuck at "Waiting for target device to come online". This is the response I get:

```
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x60000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554

09/19 16:25:06: Launching app
Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.
```

What else can I do?

**EDIT**: My PC specs:

- Windows 10 Pro x64
- Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU Q8300 @ 2.50GHz 2.50GHz
- 8.00 GB RAM
- NVIDIA GeForce GT 610
- 190GB free space

Comment: Please edit your question to include: Computer Model, OS, CPU, GPU, memory (RAM and free space on disk).

Comment: @MorrisonChang Done, please take a look.

Comment: My only suggestion is to check for any antivirus/firewall if you are on a corporate network computer and add the build number for Win 10 (since there is the original and anniversary edition) to help others.

Answer (score 0):

Under Android SDK Manager you have to install Intel x86 Emulator Installer there. [Android SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTUaJ.png)

check it out also:
[Error in launching AVD with AMD processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd-with-amd-processor)

Answer (score 0):

First, click on **File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart**.

If this solution is not working, try to update the `build.gradle` of your project.
For example, update the `compileSdkVersion` to 25, (the supports libs to 25), the `buildToolsVersion` 25.0.2 and the `targetSdkVersion` to 25. Don't forget to sync your gradle after that.