# how to enable nx with my cpu

Tags: haxm, nomachine-nx

i newly installed android studio and i receive that i cant install haxm because i dont have nx 
i have intel core (TM) i3 , but i cant enable this feature on bios , how can i enable this feature? 
my cpu doesn't support that ?
please help me to understand this problem.
i check that with coreinfo and it shows that nx is disable , but after i go to the bios, after hours i cant enable nx in bios, and i dont see any options that can help me , so after that i search , and i cant see problems that as silimar as me , and i asked this question
could you help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in launching AVD with AMD processor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd-with-amd-processor)

Comment: i try to solve my problem with your way but i it doesnt work and my problem still exists !! i really need to solve because i want to use virtual device in android studio and this problem dont allow me , so its really bothering me , please help me ...

Comment: You can use a tool to find out if your processor has nx support or not (HWINFO32/HWINFO64 - for example). I'm no expert in Android development, but if you don't have the required processor features it seems that you can run a slower arm emulator.