# How can I solve it when run my app it give this error

Tags: android

---

this error appear when my android app run how can I solve it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyMM0.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error is advising you to install Intel HAXM.

[See the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38216500/3550988) for instructions.