# HAXM is not installed on this machine

Tags: android, xamarin

Recently I've installed Xamarin and tried to do a tutorial in Xamarin page [beginner](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/hello,android_quickstart/). When I am about to compile, it gives me an error:

> 2>Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.

and

> 2>CPU acceleration status: HAXM is not installed on this machine

Then I am opening the android SDK Manager, I can't install the HAXM

[image]
[image]
Some link suggest to download it from intel but I got access denied. And also in  my windows feature hyper-v was unchecked

[image] 
[image]

**n.b:** I am using windows ver.10, VS.studio ver.2017 with i5 processor

Answer (score 49):

1. Open SDK Manager and download **Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator** (HAXM installer) if you haven't.
2. Now go to your SDK directory (C:\users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk, generally). In this directory, go to **extras → Intel → Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager** and run the file named "**intelhaxm-android.exe**".

   > In case you get an error like "Intel virtualization technology
   >   (vt,vt-x) is not enabled", go to your BIOS settings and enable
   >   hardware virtualization.
3. Restart Android Studio and then try to start the AVD again.

It might take a minute or 2 to show the emulator window.

Please this answer for images
[Error in launching AVD with AMD processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd-with-amd-processor/30129536#30129536)

Comment: sorry, iam not quite detailed. even i check on the HAXM installer. i can't install packages

Comment: uploaded on picture2

Comment: @chopperfield Make sure virtualization is turned on in BIOS.

Comment: @GabeSechan i have turned it on, but still can't install the packages

Comment: @user2455320 iam using xamarin. still can't installing the packages

Comment: That's work for me. Why they download it but not preintall it. So we can do some work instead of wasting our time. Thanks @Ashok Kateshiya

Comment: You will find **Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)** in the very bottom of the Android SDK Manager, under **Extras**:
https://imgur.com/a/KaaBr05.

You probably need to run Android SDK Manager as administrator.

Comment: Thanks... this answer help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 5):

Check your system have `Intel® VT-x Technology`, sometime it is easier to make mistake.

Check your `Intel Virtualization Technology` state in `Task Manager -> Performance -> Virtualization -> Enable or Disable`.
[image]

In BIOS model :

1. **Even if you do this, it maybe still have no effect** :

   `Config -> CPU -> Intel Virtualization Technology -> Enable`
2. **Enable Virtualization like this** :

   `Security -> Virtualization -> Intel(R) Virtualization Technology -> Enabled`

If you have turn it on, install the [Intel HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows).

Comment: iam sory, i haven't test it, because i got other project. i will review it in near future. thanks !. i though this is gonna be useful so i won't delete the post

Comment: I was having the same problem as chopperfield - specifically where the Android SDK Manager was showing that the HAXM installer was not compatible with Windows.  I followed the link ( Intel HAXM -
 https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows ) that @York Shen - MSFT supplied and was able to get it manually installed and running it properly.

Comment: You literally saved my life, I didn't think to look there, I debugged everything but nothing worked thanks

Comment: Perfect Solution @York Shen

Answer (score 5):

If it is Intel processor, then you enable Intel HAXM.

If it is AMD processor then below is your answer.

You absolutely don't need Intel HAXM (Hardware Accelerated Execution Mode) in AMD processors, because they are AMD processors.

Just enable (check) Windows Hypervisor Platform in Windows features as shown below.
[image]

Now, you can start emulators. No need of Intel HAXM.

Here is official link: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html

Answer (score 4):

As Ashok Kateshiya post says, do follow same. But for first step that how to get the things, A new user of Android SDK who is going to setup the software may get confused somewhat. SO I am adding some extra details for them. Just see down...

I am adding an image for how to get the first option, here... [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LSrr.png)

Now, click apply and follow the steps and atlast click ok butoon.

Now go to your SDK directory (C:\users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk, generally). In this directory, go to extras → Intel → Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager.
And run the file named "haxm-7.6.5-setup.exe".

Now it will install the exe file and by using a intel interface.
And you need not to restart the android studio just run the app it will work fine for you.

Adding an image for succefull completion of installation: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9c1Um.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check HAXM installed 
Goto Controll pannel check HAXM (or check C:\Windows\System32\drivers\IntelHaxm.sys)

You can download HAXM version xxx and install (or you can download in android studio you will see it in you_path\SDK\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager)

If you install HAXM  and get error "VT-x Technology...." => so you much checkin **driver BIOS and chipset installed**  AND **CHECKING BIOS Intel(R) Virtualization Technology -> Enabled**

If Are you on Windows 7? I suspect this issue only affects 64-bit Windows 7 systems that lack a security patch, which enables support for SHA-256 code signing algorithm:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46148

Answer (score 0):

Try the following...

1. Download the latest version of HAXM from https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases
2. Copy the contents of the zip to "..sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager" (create the folders if they don't exist)
3. Open a Command Prompt in administrator mode.
4. Change the directory given in step 2.
5. Run silent_install.bat. You should see the message "Intel HAXM installed successfully!"
6. Restart Android Studio and open the emulator again.