# is it possible to run android emulator on client's virtual machine?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-emulator

We are working remotely on client's virtual machine. I keep getting the VT-X/disabling hyper-V error even after doing the needful.
So, my question is , is it possible to run emulator, which is itself a VM on another VM?
If not, suggest a way to work around this problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Generally you can run an emulator on a virtual machine. More specific you maybe need to set some settings and install things.

Comment: "after doing the needful" is extremely unclear

Comment: Please post the complete "VT-X/disabling hyper-V error" message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible to run android emulator on client's virtual machine?

I think the problem is not you are working remotely on client's virtual machine, the problem is that your Physical machines turn on the Windows feature : `Hyper-V`, but when you run an Android Emulator, it needs to [disabling the `Hyper-V`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/android-sdk-emulator/1-hardware-acceleration/#Disabling_Hyper-V), so it gives the `VT-X/disabling hyper-V error`.

I have test working remotely on client's virtual machine and turn on the `Hyper-V`. When I run an Android emulator from Android Studio, it failed and gives me the error message :

[image]

To solve this problem, you should turn off your `hyper-v` and restart the computer. If you cant do this, you could try using [Visual Studio Emulator for Android](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.sg%2F). As the document said :

> with Hyper-V compatibility you can run the emulator side-by-side with the Windows Phone Emulator and other Hyper-V VMs

Then, you could run the [Android emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc6dK.png).

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: @SRKprakash, is this answer helpful? If yes, could you please mark this answer?

Comment: I appreciate the pains that you took to come up with a solution.

Comment: However, I am still unable to rectify this issue.

Comment: I suspect that VT-x is turned off. I do not know how to access system BIOS of client's VM to turn it on..

Comment: @SRKprakash, it's possible that you may refer to this case： [HAXM is not installed on this machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273905/haxm-is-not-installed-on-this-machine/45293851#45293851).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about what happens in a VM.
But, emulator is not possible in nested VM. I found that out while installing android studio when I got the error message explaining the same.

Regarding working emulator with VM, we can go with @Grace Feng