# HAXM installation issues: VS2107+Xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator, haxm

In the SDK Manager, I see that HAXM installer isn't compatible with Windows for some reason. Refer screenshot:

[image]

I am using Xamarin with VS2017 Enterprise. I have disabled Secure Boot from my BIOS settings and Virtualization is enabled. It's a W530 laptop, with 16 gig RAM and 1 TB HDD on Windows 10. I downloaded `haxm-windows_v6_2_1.zip (6.2.1)` from here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm and when I run `intelhaxm-android.exe`, it throw this error:

[image]

The emulator is an x86 phone and not an ARM one, as, apparently, the former is 10 times more faster (It throws that message). The skeletal project build with no issues 
[image]

so I know the Android APIs are all correctly set with the target framework version. So when I select my custom emulator (x86 - API 25), in seconds, a deployment error is thrown:
[image]

The Output for Build shows this:

```
1>Starting deploy x86_API25 ...
1>Starting emulator x86_API25 ...
1>C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -avd x86_API25 -prop monodroid.avdname=x86_API25
1>emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
1>Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
1>CPU acceleration status: Please disable Hyper-V before using the Android Emulator.  Start a command prompt as Administrator, run 'bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off', reboot.
1>Emulator x86_API25 cannot be started.
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

And yes, Hyper-V IS disabled! It was done from the Command Line in Admin mode!

*I have done what ever I did only after scanning the entire Stack Overflow site (and couple of other websites) so yes, I have done my homework.*

Please help!

[image: BIOS Screen 1]

[image: BIOS Screen 2]

[image: BIOS Screen 3]

Turn Windows feature on or off:
[image]

Comment: Please refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273905/haxm-is-not-installed-on-this-machine/45293851#45293851

Comment: Every condition under that is met. I just don't know how I should proceed. Anything else you can take a look at?

Comment: First, please make sure you have **Enable Virtualization** : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273905/haxm-is-not-installed-on-this-machine/45293851#45293851

Comment: have you solved your problem?

Comment: I didn't know how to prove to you that I have ENABLED VIRTUALIZATION, so attached are some screenshots of my BIOS screen. What else can you suggest?

Comment: It seems you didn't disable your  `Hyper-V`, but as you said, " **Hyper-V** IS disabled! It was done from the Command Line in Admin mode!". So could you please share the command that you used to disable the **Hyper-V** ?

Comment: Here's the command that I used: **bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off**. Also, attached is the screenshot of my 'Turn Windows feature on or off' window. Please let me know if I can do anything else.

Comment: Even if you have enabled the Virtualization(VT) in BIOS settings, some antivirus options prevent HAXM installation.

Comment: Have you install `Avast` antivirus  in your computer?

Comment: No Avast. It's Windows Defender Security Center - Company laptop - And I don't see any relevant setting in it.

Comment: No one's got anything? Strange! I also deployed a whole new project, and the same thing. Not like I was expecting anything to change. So yea, the issue is still unresolved.

Comment: FYI, I tried this also: `dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V-All` - No joy.

Comment: Also tried this: Enabled Hyper-V and disabled it with `dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V-All`. Still the same issue. Running `intelhaxm-android` as an Administrator.

Comment: And, please don't suggest I use a/my Android phone as test bed! Honestly, I've tried that and it works, but that I'd like to leave as my last resort.

Comment: Sorry for late, you could open a new question in [Technet forums - Hyper-V - Microsoft](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/home?forum=winserverhyperv) for a better solution.

Comment: Ok, done that: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/36883c00-16cc-4710-8eed-4848c2d83235/haxm-installation-issues-vs2107xamarin?forum=winserverhyperv