# android emulator is not working due to haxm?

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to run android emulator on android studio but it always kept prompting that haxm is not installed and always give option to install haxm and i installed it every time then it shows its successfully done then again when i run emulator it show haxm is not installed.

I tried every thing that I found on internet. But emulator is not starting it kept showing haxm is not installed but when i try to installed it show its already installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HAXM is not installed on this machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273905/haxm-is-not-installed-on-this-machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not say what you did. Bu what is what I did for it to work.
As admin from command prompt

1. check if installed `sc query intelhaxm`

   ```html
   [SC] EnumQueryServicesStatus:OpenService FAILED 1060:

   The specified service does not exist as an installed service.
   ```

   Service not installed, need to install
2. install `haxm-7.8.0-setup.exe`. I downloaded from https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases
3. check if installed `sc query intelhaxm`

```html
SERVICE_NAME: intelhaxm
        TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 31  (0x1f)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

It will say to stop Hyper-V if it works like this.

4.`bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`
The operation completed successfully.
it will also ask to restart for disable operation to to take effect.

5. `restart`
   Query againg for service state
6. `sc query intelhaxm`

   ```html
   SERVICE_NAME: intelhaxm
       TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
       STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                               (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
       WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
       SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
       CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
       WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
   ```

   From android SDK check
7. Android\Sdk\emulator>emulator-check.exe accel
   accel:
   0
   HAXM version 7.8.0 (4) is installed and usable.
   accel
   After runnin an emulation with kernel logs
8. I see in qemu logs 4 encounters

> 8.1. VERBOSE | CPU Acceleration status: HAXM version 7.8.0 (4) is installed and usable.
> 8.2. INFO    |      argv[16] = "-enable-hax"
> 8.3. INFO    | Concatenated QEMU options: "lala;a-bla-bla-bla pstore.bin -cpu android64 -enable-hax
> 8.4. HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.

I hope it helps.
p.s. someone I had to run emulator from Studio twice for it to kick in otherwise no issues...