# Emulator wont launch: Error while waiting for device

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-emulator

I am trying to build an app and my android emulator won't load.

Here is the error:

> "Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Nexus_4_API_22 was killed."

These also pop up on the right side when it runs:

> "Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1"
>
> "Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!"

I do not have any code yet just testing a layout.

I have tried everything I have found on the internet I searched up all of the errors and have found nothing that has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open SDK Manager and download **Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator** (HAXM installer) if you haven't.
2. Now go to your SDK directory (C:\users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk, generally). In this directory, go to **extras → Intel → Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager** and run the file named "**intelhaxm-android.exe**".

   > In case you get an error like "Intel virtualization technology
   >   (vt,vt-x) is not enabled", go to your BIOS settings and enable
   >   hardware virtualization.
3. Restart Android Studio and then try to start the AVD again.

It might take a minute or 2 to show the emulator window.

<[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27997670/9530467)>

Comment: when i run i am getting a pop up that says next and then after that it says change repair or remove.

Comment: You get this options when you run what, exactly?

Comment: intelhaxm-android.exe

Comment: Did you try choosing the option "Repair"?

Comment: Just tried Repair and Change are grayed out and wont let me use them

Comment: I don't know then, I'm sorry =[