# Android Studio: can't able to run emulation

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, haxm

I tried to run Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager for android studio emulator.
I got this error while installation.

[image]

But I have already enabled Vt-x. still "Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) is not turned On" error shown

[image]

Please help me how to fix this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in launching AVD with AMD processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd-with-amd-processor)

Answer (score 0):

To support `x64 images` to be virtualized you need to enable your *Intel virtualization technology* **On**. This is done from the **BIOS menu** of your computer.

So you need to `boot to your BIOS menu and enable the Intel-VT option`.

[Here](https://2nwiki.2n.cz/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=75202968)'s a guide to help you do this.

Comment: I have enabled Virtualization technology in BIOS but still, it shows same error