# error in using nexus 5X API 28 in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When I try to run the hello world project I'm getting such errors:

> Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!

There are numbers of solutions on the internet but none working for me.

What can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in launching AVD with AMD processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd-with-amd-processor)

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen above solution could not solve my problem

Comment: The right solution depends on the CPU of your computer. With modern Intel CPUs you should follow the instruction for using Intel HAXM. Otherwise (like with an AMD CPU) you should use ARM based "armeabi" virtual machines.

Comment: ...and of course you can use "armeabi" in any case, but the emulator will then be much slower than with an x86 virtual machine with HAXM enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows for development, you need to enable hardware acceleration in bios setting on your system

Comment: yes im using windows.How can i do that can you guide a bit ?