# Suddenly cant open Emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, virtualization, amd-processor

i started my PC today and all of a sudden I cant get my emulator to start in AndroidStudio.

I have an AMD Ryzen 2600X

It says HAXM is not installed.
I have HyperV disabled, I have Windows-Hypervisor-Platform enabled. It used to work just yesterday, idk what changed. Virtualization is on too.

I tried `"bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off"` in cmd but nothing seems to work.

Reinstalled Android Studio, still nothing. Did ALL the steps 5 times in a row, still nothing.. what is going on?

Comment: I have the same issue - for the time I'm using emulator I disable the hyper-v service.

Comment: Look at that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54890457/5255770

Comment: So do I, still doesnt work for me.

Comment: or disable hyper-v like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53136773/5255770

Comment: You have to disable hyper-v to run HAXM.

Comment: I did all these steps already, still nothing. That is why its so weird, it literally worked yesterday

Comment: Update android emulator to the newest version.

Comment: Its at 30.0.5, i think its the most recent

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/38216500/5255770

Comment: The link doesnt work anymore, but I already tried installing HAXM and it won't let me because "This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) or it is being exclusively used by Hyper-V. HAXM cannot be installed. 
Please ensure Hyper-V is disabled in Windows Features, or refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information."

Im positive Hyper-V is disabled

Comment: Did you reboot your computer after disabling hyper-v?

Comment: Yes, I did reboot it about 30 times today. I might just go ahead and reinstall everything Im out of ideas

Comment: It's better to try other ways: How's your bios? maybe your bios has been restored? Also uninstalling hyper-v, not disabling will help for 100%

Comment: What do you mean by that? I enabled SVM under CPU Configuration. 
I might need HyperV when I use OracleVM don't I?